# Problem with python manipulating words from a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting using python 3 to create an automated script to check some ASN (as numbers) and I have the bellow issue.
Also this is my first post and I hope I provide all the info.

I have a test file that looks like this:

```
AS197655 # first line
AS100 AS10000 AS10002 AS10002 AS10006 # second line
```

and for this test file, I want the output to be like this:

```
AS197655
AS100
AS10000
AS10002
AS10002
AS10006
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
with open ("test", 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
         line = line.strip()
         print(line)
```

If i run that code I get:

```
AS197655
AS100 AS10000 AS10002 AS10002 AS10006
```

Comment: Could you more clearly explain the difference between what you have now and what you need the script to do? It looks to me like you are getting what you want already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the lines using the split function.

```
with open ("test", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for l in line.strip().split():
            print(l)
```

Result:

```
AS197655
AS100
AS10000
AS10002
AS10002
AS10006
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
with open("test", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        for elem in line.strip().split(" "):
            print(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the newline with " " and split the string which will give you the list. Later, you can loop through the list to write the contents to a file.

```
with open ("sample", 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
          line = line.replace("\n", "").split()
        for word in line:
          print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip` only removes surrounding whitespace from each line. In order to split each line by whitespace, one can use `str.split` with no arguments instead.

```
with open ("test", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for y in line.split():
            print(y)
```

Answer (score -6):

Please try:

```
data = open("test", 'r').readlines()
```

Is `data[0]` your first ine, and `data[1]` your second line?

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?